# ROS FUERTE install

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I'm having troubles when I try to install ROS FUERTE in Ubuntu 14.04. I already have installed ROS INDIGO and I need to install ROS FUERTE.
I follow the page's steps:

1. Setup source.list
   sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu precise main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
2. Setup keys
   wget http://packages.ros.org/ros.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
3. Update

Result of the last is:

Doesn't exist available public key to ID
Imposible to get : http://ppa.launchpad.net/beineri/opt-qt541-trusty/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

Imposible to get:  http://ppa.launchpad.net/beineri/opt-qt541-trusty/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

Finally when I try:

sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-desktop-full

The result is:

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

ros-fuerte-desktop-full : Depends: ros-fuerte-nodelet-core (= 1.6.5-s1367543602~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-geometry-tutorials (= 0.1.3-s1367543014~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-orocos-kinematics-dynamics (= 0.2.3-s1367486085~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-filters (= 1.6.0-s1367543501~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-slam-gmapping (= 1.2.7-s1371543634~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-simulator-gazebo (= 1.6.16-s1371459371~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-visualization (= 1.8.17-s1371542460~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-vision-opencv (= 1.8.8-s1367542520~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-perception-pcl (= 1.2.5-s1371449986~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-geometry-experimental (= 0.2.3-s1367542184~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-robot-model-visualization (= 0.1.2-s1367526937~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-common-tutorials (= 0.2.3-s1367556725~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-image-pipeline (= 1.8.5-s1371458788~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-bfl (= 0.1.0-s1367486082~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-diagnostics-monitors (= 1.4.3-s1367543711~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-common-rosdeps (= 1.2.0-s1367477294~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-geometry-visualization (= 0.1.1-s1367555057~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-image-common (= 1.8.0-s1367543911~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-bond-core (= 1.6.3-s1367525391~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-python-qt-binding (= 0.1.9-s1367564963~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-visualization-common (= 1.8.4-s1367527510~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-physics-ode (= 1.8.0-s1367477775~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-driver-common (= 1.4.0-s1367556463~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-executive-smach (= 1.2.1-s1367541334~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-stage (= 1.6.6-s1367542509~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-dynamic-reconfigure (= 1.4.2-s1367525734~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-image-transport-plugins (= 1.8.6-s1367557303~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-xacro (= 1.6.1-s1367527622~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-robot-model (= 1.8.1-s1367542439~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-bullet (= 2.79-s1367485580~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-pluginlib (= 1.8.0-s1367527028~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-geometry (= 1.8.2-s1367526247~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-visualization-tutorials (= 0.6.3-s1371545777~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-executive-smach-visualization (= 1.0.2-s1367554670~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-laser-pipeline (= 1.4.5-s1371539763~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-robot-model-tutorials (= 0.1.2-s1367478489~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-common (= 1.8.0-s1367543382~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-diagnostics (= 1.6.4-s1367543439~precise) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-fuerte-navigation (= 1.8.3-s1371541802~precise) but it is not going to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Any help will be much grateful!!

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234522/ros-fuerte-install/) by [mafr90](https://answers.ros.org/users/23673/mafr90/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-05-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To start, ROS Fuerte is no longer supported. You should make a strong effort to use a newer version of ROS.

As described in the [fuerte installation instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu), Fuerte was only supported on Ubuntu 10.04, 11.10 and 12.04. This means that the compiled binary packages for Fuerte will have dependencies that are specific to those versions of Ubuntu, and they won't work with newer Ubuntu versions.

It may be possible to build Fuerte from source on Ubuntu 14.04, but you will likely run into compatibility issues with some of the dependencies, since dependencies such as PCL have changed considerably between Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1